# problema en formulario

Tags: javascript, html5

En mi formulario tengodos select que funcionan de acuerdo al otro y toda la información que se de en ese formulario se envia a un WhatsApp, pero en el value de mis selct los tengo como 1 y 2 y afuera de ello pues lainformación que llevará, a lo que voy es que cuando se envia la informacion no me pone la informacion que pido si no el numero que esta dentro del value.
Quiero que no me mande ya sea el 1 o 2 de los value de select yo quiero recibir ya sea soldador o publico

```js
<script>
    var provincias_1=new Array("-","Porton","Puerta","Ventana","Otro","...");
    var provincias_2=new Array("-","Corte CNC","Rolado","Otro","...");
   
  
    var todasProvincias = [
      [],
      provincias_1,
      provincias_2,
      
    ];
  
    function cambia_provincia(){ 
         //tomo el valor del select del pais elegido 
         var pais 
         pais = document.f1.pais[document.f1.pais.selectedIndex].value 
         //miro a ver si el pais está definido 
         if (pais != 0) { 
            //si estaba definido, entonces coloco las opciones de la provincia correspondiente. 
            //selecciono el array de provincia adecuado 
            mis_provincias=todasProvincias[pais]
            //calculo el numero de provincias 
            num_provincias = mis_provincias.length 
            //marco el número de provincias en el select 
            document.f1.provincia.length = num_provincias 
            //para cada provincia del array, la introduzco en el select 
            for(i=0;i<num_provincias;i++){ 
               document.f1.provincia.options[i].value=mis_provincias[i] 
               document.f1.provincia.options[i].text=mis_provincias[i] 
            }   
         }else{ 
            //si no había provincia seleccionada, elimino las provincias del select 
            document.f1.provincia.length = 1 
            //coloco un guión en la única opción que he dejado 
            document.f1.provincia.options[0].value = "-" 
            document.f1.provincia.options[0].text = "-" 
         } 
         //marco como seleccionada la opción primera de provincia 
         document.f1.provincia.options[0].selected = true 
  }
  
    </script>
```

```html
<form id="formulario" class="formulario"  name="f1">
    <h1>Cotizaciones por WhatsApp</h1>
    <div class="box-input">
        <input name="nombre" id="nombre" type="text" required>
        <span data-placeholder="Nombre completo"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="box-input">
        <input name="apellidos" id="apellidos" type="number" required>
        <span data-placeholder="Celular"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="box-input">
        <input name="postal" id="postal" type="number" required>
        <span data-placeholder="Código Postal" ></span>
    </div>
    <select name=pais id="pais" onchange="cambia_provincia()" class="styled-select"> 
        <option value="0" selected>Seleccione... 
        <option value="1">Público en grl 
        <option value="2">Soldador o Herrero 
     
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <select name=provincia id="provincia" class="styled-select"> 
        <option value="-">- 
        </select> <br><br><br>
    <button id="submit" type="submit" class="boton"><i class=""></i> Enviar WhatsApp</button>
</form>

utilizo JavaScript para enviar todo a mi whats pero les decia que me manda solo el nnumero y es el unico error ya que lo demas si lo hace, solo es en el de soldador o publico porque en el tipo de trabajo si lo pone.

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. No es la respuesta a tu pregunta, pero esos `<option>` sin `</option>`... las etiquetas se cierran, so pena de depender de que el navegador suponga cosas o te pinte cualquier cosa.

Comment: Hola Alfabravo, si me funciona asi como lo tengo, pero mi problema es que quiero recibir ya sea soldador o publio y no el 1 o 2

Comment: La pregunta es clara y por eso dije, no es respuesta. La sugerencia es que tu documento tenga sintaxis correcta. Que "te funcione así" significa que el navegador está suponiendo cosas y eso un díá de estos se te devuelve y te muerde la nariz :)  Pregunta: cuando dices que se envía a un whatsapp, es cuando le das al botón? Lo que pasa es que ese submit va a enviar sólo los valores del formulario y para el select sólo se envía el value del option seleccionado. Te toca no hacer submit y leer el formulario con JS, agarrar el value y texto del option y enviarlo de otra forma...

Comment: No veo inconvenientes, mas bien prueba cambiando el valor del lado de tu servidor. Si recibes en tu action el pais es valor 1, entonces conviértelo a cadena. `if($pais ==1){ $pais_x="Publico en gral";}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes implementar algo así, es una sugerencia:

**TU FORMULARIO**

```html
<script>
  var options1=new Array("","Porton","Puerta","Ventana","Otro","...");
  var options2=new Array("","Corte CNC","Rolado","Otro","...");

  var allOptions = [
    [],
    options1,
    options2,
    
  ];
  
  function change_select(){ 
    var oficio 
    oficio = document.f1.oficio[document.f1.oficio.selectedIndex].value 

    if (oficio != 0) { 
      myOptions=allOptions[oficio]
      numOptions = myOptions.length 
      document.f1.options.length = numOptions 
      
      for(i=0;i<numOptions;i++){ 
          document.f1.options.options[i].value=myOptions[i] 
          document.f1.options.options[i].text=myOptions[i] 
      }   
    }else{ 
      document.f1.options.length = 1 
      document.f1.options.options[0].value = "-" 
      document.f1.options.options[0].text = "-" 
    } 
    document.f1.options.options[0].selected = true 
  }
  
  </script>

<form id="formulario" class="formulario" name="f1" action="action.php">

  <h1>Cotizaciones por WhatsApp</h1>

  <div class="box-input">
      <input name="nombre" id="nombre" type="text" required placeholder="Nombre">
      <span data-placeholder="Nombre completo"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="box-input">
      <input name="celular" id="Celular" type="number" required placeholder="Celular">
  </div>

  <div class="box-input">
      <input name="postal" id="postal" type="number" required placeholder="Codigo Postal">
  </div>

  <select name=oficio id="oficio" onchange="change_select()" class="styled-select"> 
    <option value="0" selected>Seleccione... </option>
    <option value="1">Publico en Gral </option>
    <option value="2">Soldador o Herrero </option>
  </select>

  <br><br>

  <select name=options id="options" class="styled-select"> 
    <option value="">Seleccione </option>
  </select> 

  <br><br><br>

  <button id="submit" type="submit" class="boton"><i class=""></i> Enviar WhatsApp</button>
</form>
```

**TU ACTION.PHP (archivo donde recibes los campos del form)**

```
<?
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$celular = $_POST['celular'];
$postal = $_POST['postal'];

$oficio = $_POST['oficio'];
$options = $_POST['options'];

function enviarMensaje(){
  if($oficio==1){
    $nombreOficio="Publico en Gral";
  }
  if($oficio==2){
    $nombreOficio="Soldador o Herrero ";
  }

  #Cuerpo del mensaje
  Echo "Hola $nombre, elegiste el oficio $nombreOficio y la opcion $opcion";
}

?>
```

EDIT: Se brindó soporte al usuario fuera de SO. La solución para convertir su variable a texto se hace de la siguiente manera en `whatsapp.js`

```
let tip = document.querySelector('#pais').value

        if (tip==1){
            varx="Publico en Gral";
        }
        if(tip==2){
            varx="Soldador o Herrero";
        }
        let ti = document.querySelector('#provincia').value
       

        let mensaje = 'send?phone=' + telefono + '&text=%0A Hola me llamo  ' + nombre + ' mi numero de celular es '+ cel + ', mi codigo postal es '+ post +' soy ' + varx + ' y quiero cotizar lo siguiente:  ' + ti + ''
```

Comment: Gracias por comentar pero entonces para enviarlo a whatsapp?

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta para que podamos ver el código que utilizas para enviarlo a Whattsapp, si es que ya te envia el mensaje

Comment: bro te escribi en tu fb